# Android: Eclipse jar icons are white and can't access classes

Tags: java, android, eclipse, jar

I downloaded a java/android library .zip file and extracted it.  Then I used the command

```
$jar -cvf java-lib-name.jar topfile/
```

and it seemed to traverse the folder and create the jar.  However, when I then move the .jar into the /libs/ folder, the icons for the packages in the jar are white instead of brown and I can't access them.  When I went into Properties->Java Build Path, the .jar is in the Private Libararies section.  Did I create the jar incorrectly?  Is there another setting in Eclipse I need to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to compile java classes before creating jar.
Or another thing you can do for this project is to import the library as android library project to your current eclipse workspace and then use it on your android project.

Add the library project using **File > Import > Existing Android Code Into Workspace.** Make sure this project is marked as a library. Right click on your project, choose **Properties**, click on Android in left pane > Under library heading, add the library project

Comment: Thanks!  I had done something similar by just importing the .jar, but then it expanded the jar into my libs folder, which I didn't want.